# Why isn't UIImage part of the Foundation framework?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uikit, foundation

I'm working on an app that allows the user to add a picture to the data model. (I'm using Realm, but I've done the same thing with CoreData and SQLite in the past.) I began building a model object with code like this:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Picture: Object {
    dynamic var imagePath: NSString = ""

    var image: UIImage {
        get {
            ...
        }
        set(UIImage) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This of course yields a Swift Compiler Error:

```
Use of undeclared type 'UIImage'
```

Adding `import UIKit` solves this problem, but then I wondered:

- Why isn't `UIImage` a data model type?
- Why isn't `UIImage` part of `Foundation`?

Does anyone know?

Comment: But why would it?! UIImage is for presenting an image on iOS, there's the NSImage counterpart for macOS. So why would UIImage be in Foundation, knowing that Foundation is shared on *all* platforms? Moreover, an image is not part of the fundamentals. Handling images should not go in Foundation but in high-level classes.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but perhaps UIImage is supposed to be used solely to present an image in the UI where the *actual* image is stored as a file or NSData.

Comment: @EricAya You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right, I've made an answer.

Comment: I like the idea that UIImage is about an in-memory backing store for displaying an image in the UI, and not a file representation object. I guess MVC is a little fractal in nature. I think of UIImage as "storing" the image and legitimately part of my data model because of this. Since images are such a common data type, it made me wonder if it shouldn't be a part of a lower level framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't UIImage part of Foundation?

Why should it be? :)

The UIImage class is for presenting an image on iOS (and the extended iOS family: watchOS, tvOS...). For macOS there's the NSImage class.

It makes sense that UIImage is not in Foundation, because Foundation is shared on all platforms.

Moreover, an image is not part of the fundamentals of a computing system, which is what the Foundation class tries to address.

Therefore handling images should not go in Foundation but in classes of higher level, possibly specialized ones for specific platforms, and that's what Apple has done with UIImage and NSImage.